# Append character to existing prompt

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to append a character based on the result of a function:

```
function prompt
{
    if (getVpnStatus) {
        Write-Host ""
    } else {
        Write-Host ""
    }
    return " "
}
```

It may come as no surprise to those of you who understand how powershell works that this overrides the prompt to only show that character (and indeed this makes sense).

What I'm wondering is, is it possible to *append* a character to the end of the current prompt - I have other modules (posh-git to be exact) which are already displaying useful information in the prompt, ideally I'd like to be able to only append the character to the end.

Comment: You can get the current prompt definition by examining the function `(gcm prompt).scriptblock`. From that I guess its technically feasible to modify the function contents to include your logic, and re-call/redefine the function with the modifications.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from [Built-in prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-5.1#built-in-prompt), you can apply [How to customize the prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-5.1#how-to-customize-the-prompt) rules:

> To customize the prompt, write a new `Prompt` function. The function
> is not protected, so you can overwrite it.

For instance (place the code snippet with ,  and `⭕` anywhere you like):

```
Set-Item -Path Function:\prompt -Value {
    $(if (Get-Command getVpnStatus) {
        if (getVpnStatus) { ' ' } else { ' ' }
    } else { '⭕ ' } ) +
    $(if (Test-Path variable:/PSDebugContext)
       { '[DBG]: ' } else { '' }) +
    'PS '+ (Get-Location) +
    '>' * ($nestedPromptLevel) +
    '> '
}
```

You could start from your current prompt instead; to get current prompt, run any of the following:

```
(Get-Command prompt).ScriptBlock              # or
(Get-Item -Path Function:\prompt).Definition
```